# Adding a Picture to my question for clarity

Tags: discussion

I posted a question to the forum.  Some members asked for a picture. How do I add a picture to my question?

Comment: I don't see a question or a picture. Perhaps there was an issue with the posting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You edit your post and use the picture icon (looks like a mountain) and add it.

Comment: True but have to have rep to add a photo I don’t remember how many was required to post a photo.+